# How to ignore symlinks or directories recursively in kdevelop?

Tags: unix, filesystems, kdevelop

I am using KDevelop 4.2.3 and in my project directory there are symbolic links to a large collection of test instances. I want to tell kdevelop to ignore these directories. There is the possibility to put a file named `.kdev_ignore` into the directory that should be ignored. Unfortunately this feature is not propagated into subdirectories.

So, is there any way to exclude a directory and all of its subdirectories without putting `.kdev_ignore` files everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

**Update with Makefile (not CMake):**

I also found a four year old Makefile symlink recursive [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=173924)  which was originally patched in Kdevelop 3.5 (plus a possible [second](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103297) reference to the same issue).

If you decide to file a new bug report, and personally I think that you should, you should reference those two links to demonstrate regression.

Comment: I am not using CMake, I build the project with a Makefile. I will try updating KDevelop. Thanks for the link to the bug, though - I was already wondering whether I am the only one affected by this issue.